# 2D collision detection when using transform.position. How to enable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path, 2d, collision

I just started with unity and followed thair 2D UFO example project.
In an effort to extend it, I came up with a quirky way of contolling my Player.

It always moves in circular paths and once I click a button, the circle's direction changes and the imaginary circle center is tanslated as shown in the picture below. That allows you to move in a figure 8 or S shape pattern and is quite fun.

[image]
However, once I figured out how to do this motion, the player object did not have any collision detection anymore.
In the original example the whole movemet handling is done within FixedUpdate(). I, however, use Update() since the former does not seem to work at all with my code (i.e. no movement at all).

This is my code for the movement so far:

```
public class ControlledRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float radius = 3f;
    public float speed = 3f;

    private float timeCounter = 0;
    private float direction = 1f;
    private Vector3 offset;

    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    void Start()
    {
    offset = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            //change the offset from the circle center and the rotation direction on keypress
            offset += new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(timeCounter), Mathf.Sin(timeCounter), 0) * radius * direction * 2;
            direction *= -1;
        }
        timeCounter += Time.deltaTime * direction * speed;
        transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(timeCounter), Mathf.Sin(timeCounter)) * radius * direction + offset;    
    }
}
```

The Plyer object has a Rigidbody 2D and a Circle Collider 2D. The walles it should collide with have Box Collider 2D. Yet, the UFO can simply pass the walls.
I assume a probable cause in the fact that I simply change transform.position or since im using Update/FixedUpdate wrong.

If you happen to have any advice on how I can keep my chosen movement control mechanism and still be able to collide with objects, I'd highly appreciate it :)

Edit:
I feel I need to go with using the rigidbody and applying some force... but I haven't figured out how to reproduce this movement with forces and also forces seem to not be super crisp in response

Comment: chances are you have a trigger?

Comment: no triggers involved

Comment: the problem with rigidbodys and circles is it by default is not their natrual movement, unless.. you made the thing in 2 parts, so the parent part is the radius of your current circles away and you apply torque so that it spins, and the child aka your actual part, moves around, and then move the radius, sounds messy but that would work - Id like to think theres a simpler idea

Comment: woah yea I thought about something similiar but that really get compex.. I had a look into the trigger and decided that I dont really need a rigidbody at all for this to work, right? I could simply use the trigger and the collider? Or do i have another misconception?

Answer (score 0):

When you need to move an object that has a Rigidbody, you need to move it using forces, you cannot do it with just transform.position, it ignores physics. that's why you cannot detect the collision.. I suggest you move it like that. I have some examples when I had to move a character that needed to interact with physics.

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
```

And this one is for moving it in certain directions:

```
//Keys for controlling the player (move and shoot) only when he's alive
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && alive)
{
  GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(transform.position + Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 4);
}
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && alive)
{
 GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(transform.position + Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * 4);
}
```

I hope it helps.. greetings :)

Comment: Thanks! I kinda figured the two wont really work well together. Question is now if I use your approach and change it so the forces make a circle or if I find a way to not use rigidbody at all and still somehow detect if I hit a wall or some other gameobject

Comment: According to this page :http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/collision-detection-without-rigid-body-in-unity    there are two possible solutions.. one of them is to make a rigidbody kinematic and catch trigger events.

Comment: yea that helped! I think i kinda got it working now with having a kinematic rigid body and a trigger collider on the player object and a non trigger collider on the walls